# Recursion in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

Long time listener, first time caller.

Im trying to learn recursion in Snowflake SQL with a classic Organizational Chart. The output Im trying for would be the total salary for each manager of employees, including both direct and indirect employees of that manager.

```
create table Employee(
    employeeid int primary key,
    managerid int,
    title string
);



INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(1,NULL,'CEO');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(2,1,'SVP 1');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(3,1,'SVP 2');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(4,2,'DIR 1');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(5,2,'DIR 2');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(6,2,'DIR 3');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(7,3,'MGR 1');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(8,3,'MGR 2');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(9,3,'MGR 3');
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE VALUES(10,9,'ASST');



create TABLE EMPLOYEE_SALARY(
    EMPLOYEE_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    SALARY INT
);


INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(1,100);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(2,90);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(3,90);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(4,80);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(5,80);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(6,80);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(7,70);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(8,70);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(9,90);
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE_SALARY VALUES(10,60);

select  
        managerid,
        sum(salary) as salary
from        
        (        
        select         emp.managerid,
                       emp.employeeid, 
                       sal.salary
        from           employee emp
        inner join     employee_salary sal on emp.employeeid = sal.employee_id   
        )
group by 1
start with     managerid is Null
connect by     managerid = prior employeeid
```

The error Im getting is "SQL compilation error: error line 3 at position 12 invalid identifier 'SALARY'".

Thanks in advance for any direction you can offer.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach this with a recursive common table expression. Snowflake supports that standard syntax, and I find it easier to follow that the `connect by` clause:

```
with cte as (
    select managerid, employeeid from employee
    union all
    select c.managerid, e.employeeid
    from cte c
    inner join employee e on e.managerid = c.employeeid
)
select c.managerid, sum(s.salary) total_salaries
from cte c
inner join employee_salary s on s.employeeid = c.employeeid
group by c.managerid
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I'd recommend the CTE approach from GMB however if you want your SQL to work here's one approach :

```
select
    managerid,
    sum(salary) salary_summed
from
(
    select
        *
    from
        (
            select
                emp.managerid,
                emp.employeeid,
                sal.salary
            from
                employee emp
                inner join employee_salary sal on emp.employeeid = sal.employee_id
        ) start with managerid is Null connect by managerid = prior employeeid
)
group by managerid
```